# android:background and android scaleType

Tags: android, background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Scale a Drawable or background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400782/android-scale-a-drawable-or-background-image)

Is it possible to set a scaleType to the background like in a imageview?

Comment: Look at this answer [CLICK HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400782/android-scale-a-drawable-or-background-image)