# Stretch background only horizontally

Tags: android, drawable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Scale a Drawable or background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400782/android-scale-a-drawable-or-background-image)

I want to set a drawable (from resources) as background of my view. But I want to stretch it only horizontally.
How can I do this?

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9362168/145046

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such scaleType that I can see. Have you tried this:

```
   <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:src="@drawable/image"
      android:scaleType="fitXY">
   </ImageView>
```

Then, you would need to place this in the background of another view, like making layers in a FrameLayout.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) . It's strechable graphic.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html) is description of tool to creating 9-patch graphic.

Comment: I tried. The problem with 9patch is that it changes paddings for my view. It is unwanted.

Comment: 9patch sets a padding to view. If for example in xml padding was not set and I expect no padding my view has if I set 9patch as background to this view - it set paddings to somthing not 0.

Comment: Have you tried 9patch without padding boxes (bottom and right black line)?

Comment: Yes. In this case padding were set to 0, but for my view other value is spevified in layout, and I want this value.