# Background image in linear layout is not well sized

Tags: android, android-layout

I made a linear layout with a background image, a png... I don't know how to show it into the layout ( and centered ) keeping proportions... here is the code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
```

Obviously image has the same height and width of the display... Any help?? Thanks in advance

=.4.S.=

Comment: Is the problem that the image is showing up skewed (wrong proportions), not filling the entire region of the LinearLayout, not centered, or some combination of the three?

Comment: well, the image fill the entire region and is centered but has wrong proportions, because it's anchored to the layout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this related question/answer:

[Android: Scale a Drawable or background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400782/android-scale-a-drawable-or-background-image)

I haven't tried it, but it sounds similar to what you're talking about.

Answer (score 8):

Thank you all ^^ I solved in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>


    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want your picture to be stretched, you can use BitmapDrawable with gravity set us instead of png.
Refer docs: [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap)