# Java (Android): How to scale a drawable without Bitmap?

Tags: android, scaling

I need to scale the background image of a button but can't turn it into a Bitmap. Here is the code right now:

```
int height = 50;
int width = 80;

Button b = new Button (this);
b. setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn);
```

Now I need to scale "R.drawable.btn" according to the "height" and "width". The setBackgroundResource won't accept a Bitmap. How do I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Because of your text "but can't turn it into a Bitmap", I fear that the second half of my answer, below, is not applicable to your question. Do you really need to keep from turning the resource "R.drawable.btn" into a Bitmap? If so, to satisfy my curiosity and to help generate a better answer, why?

Comment: Because the btn.setBackgroundResource doesn't let me set a Bitmap as a background. I think I also tried btn.setBackgroundDrawable, now I'm going to try it again.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can allow the layout parameters to control the scale or you can scale the image yourself.

Allow the layout to scale the image:

```
b.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn));
```

Scale the image manually:

```
Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.btn);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original, width, height, false);
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), b);
button.setBackground(d);
```

***Warning**: The image may not appear onscreen scaled exactly as you expect. This is because depending on the layout parameters of your `Button`, Android may additionally scale the image based on the hardware screen density of your device.*

Comment: Isn't setBackgroundDrawable deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

this will turn a bitmap into a drawable

```
image = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),MenuScreen.image1);
```

image is the drawable and image1 is the bitmap