# How can I align my backgroundimage?

Tags: android, image, background

I want to align my background image which I declare in the activity_main.xml:

```
android:background="@drawable/spieler_blau"
```

The problem is that the whole screen is filled with this picture and I want to have a small white space on the left side of the screen. Like that:

[image]

Any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give some left margin to the layout. Also, post your xml layout for the exact solution.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1413084/1278748

Comment: Can you post your xml file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Here is output]

You can use     `android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"`. You can set margin as per requirement.

Or you can also create one blank `View` and one `ImageView` in xml and give it weight.

Example:

1)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/expandable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >



    <View  android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

**OR** 2)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/expandable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats is perfect for me. Again ;).

Comment: @Sander glad to help you again :)

Comment: At the moment I have a white margin. How can I get it off? I mean on the bottom right and top side. So that the image fills the whole screen. Just the left side has to be white for my other option which I want to fill.

Comment: Ah, thanks alot I found it. I had

android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

in the .xml file and got a margin in it. Anyways - thanks alot Hardy.

Answer (score 1):

IF you need space to remain in left side,
There possible ways can be,

1. Set Imageview SRC, not the background , and give padding at left side
2. Create your background drawable with transparent space on left side
3. Or you create a custom view

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding padding to the left of the image layout with the `android:paddingLeft` attribute:

```
<ImageView android:background="@drawable/spieler_blau"
   android:paddingLeft="10dp"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: Padding is the property for the Contents inside the view, will not affect the background..