# How to set scaletype for RelativeLayout's background image?

Tags: android, xml

How do I set the `android:scaletype` attribute for the background image of a `RelativeLayout`? The XML code is below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

Comment: you cannot set scaletype for relative layout background image instead you can place image view with same width and height of the relative layout and set scale type for the image view

Comment: KMI: Ok. Where should I put the ImageView? Inside relative layout?

Comment: yes put inside the relative layout

Comment: May i know ? why you want to use the scale type for relative layout background image?

Comment: The background image is long lengthwise so I want to crop out the extra length of the image and only show the amount of image that fits into the phone's resolution. Also KMI, there are other things in my relativelayout so how do I keep the new ImageView with the background at the back and the other buttons etc on the front of the screen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Scale a Drawable or background image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400782/android-scale-a-drawable-or-background-image)