# Background drawable aspect ratio

Tags: android, background, drawable

I have this layout for a cell from a GridView calendar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_cell"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/cell_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/shape_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm setting programatically a drawable background to Linear layout identified as `android:id="@+id/shape_background`. I inserted this layout just because I don't want distortions related to size of parent LinearLayout. As you noticed I have 2 textviews inside it. If the layout width and height is wrap_content my background shrinks to the size of content inside textviews. And when I set to match_parent occurs distortions on shaped background when I rotate.
Below is the simple code to create drawable and its initialization.

```
public CalendarAdapter( Context context, int month, int year,
                        Map<String, Object> caldroidData,
                        Map<String, Object> extraData, int cellHeight) {
        super(context, month, year, caldroidData, extraData);
        this.cellHeight = (int)Math.floor( ( cellHeight - ( cellHeight * 0.1 ) ) /6 );
        backgroundDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable( context, R.drawable.ball );
    }

LinearLayout shapeBackground = ( LinearLayout )cellView.findViewById( R.id.shape_background );
backgroundDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 90, 90);
backgroundDrawable = new ScaleDrawable( backgroundDrawable, 0, 90, 90).getDrawable();
shapeBackground.setBackground( backgroundDrawable );
```

And this is the xml of drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
    <size
        android:width="1dp"
        android:height="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

Pretty simple. I read some SO posts and tried the solutions. No success.

Some images:
[image]
[image]

[Android: Scale a Drawable or background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400782/android-scale-a-drawable-or-background-image)

[How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)

Comment: The very same problem occurs with regular drawable, and bitmaps.

Comment: @PN10 This was already made. See my drawable

Comment: where is your xml drawable code??

Comment: @PN10 Sorry, xml hadn't been appear

Comment: any update on this question?