# How to crop multiple part of image file in android?

Tags: android

[image]

show this image in multiple part of crop.and save this multiple crop parts in different files.

Comment: Any other commands?

Comment: @greenapps lol hahaha

Comment: bro its not a joke

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with XML **ImageViewes**

Maybe you can play with the scaleType and scaleX-Y (example.: with a bar) and you can save the **ImageView** Bitmap as a File or a Drawable in the resources.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400782/android-scale-a-drawable-or-background-image) (little help)

Comment: but i want to code or thardparty tool for crop of image multiple parts

Comment: Then you should *most probably* make sure you add the right license to your code/application, given you find such.